# How do I restrict fold expressions with C++ 20 requirements/concepts?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts, fold-expression

How do you restrict the allowed types in variadic templates and fold expression using C++20 concepts?

For example suppose I'd like to restrict the following fold expression to only support integral types, how would I do that?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Args> // requires (is_integral<Args>::value )
    int sum(Args... args) { return (... + args); }
int main()
{
    cout << sum(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: Note that constraints can be an inferior alternative for such use cases. What do you win? Maybe better error messages. However, you lose flexibility, as you now can't sum doubles and ints, and you also can't apply it to overloaded classes. Without the constraint, the compiler will directly complain if the `+` can't be applied, so there is no real point in premature checking via a constraint what the compiler finds anyway.

Answer (score 31):

The minimal change to make it work is:

```
requires (std::is_integral<Args>::value && ...)
```

I'd also suggest using the less verbose `is_integral_v<...>` instead of `is_integral<...>::value`.

Or, even better, a concept:

```
template <std::integral ...Args> // no requires needed
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use *type-constraint* `auto` syntax:

```
int sum(std::integral auto... args) { return (... + args); }
```